# Spark on EMR "exceeding memory limits" for checkpointed/cached job

Tags: caching, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, apache-spark-2.0, checkpointing

Is my understanding of caching wrong? The resulting RDD after all my transformations is incredibly small, like 1 GB. The data it was computed from is quite large, ~700 GB in size.

I have to run logic to read in thousands of pretty big files, all to compute the much smaller resulting RDD. Each iteration processes the next batch of 400 files, which when read in can blow up to around 700 GB in size. Incoming RDD's are processed (read and transformed) in the same way, and then union'ed with the accumulating RDD. I **cache and checkpoint** after each iteration (also **unpersisting (with blocking = true)** the old version of the resulting rdd) so that I can cut the RDD lineage, so that I won't have to recompute the results if something goes wrong, and to save space on the executors. **So, I figured that at any time I really only need 1 GB * number of iterations + ~750GB of memory total for my job, and that 1.6 TB should be more than enough.** But apparently I am misunderstanding something.

On each iteration, GC time is getting longer and longer. Spark UI on shows the executors are in the red zone (> 10% time spent on GC). The whole job then fails on perhaps the 3rd or 4th iteration with messages like *MemoryLimit exceeded*, *Lost Executor/no path to executor*, and YARN kills off my executors. I thought that by caching and checkpointing I am saving a lot of space on my executors. I just don't understand if there is some sort of memory leak? **Why is the memory continuing to fill up?**

I'm running Spark 2.1.1 on EMR with m3.large instances. My cluster is limited to ~1.6 TB in size. I run with the following configuration:

```
driver-memory 8g
deploy-mode cluster 
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=100 
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=200
spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
executor-cores 4 
executor-memory 8g
```

What my code sort of looks like:

```
var accRdd = <empty>
val batchSize = 400
var iteration = 1
filesToIngest.grouped(batchSize).foreach {
    val transformedRdd = transform(accRdd).reduceByKey((row1, row2) => 
      combine(row1, row2)
    )
    val oldAccRdd = accRdd
    accRdd = accRdd.union(transformedRdd).reduceByKey((row1, row2) => 
      combine(row1, row2)
    ).coalesce(5 + i)
    accRdd.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
    accRdd.checkpoint()
    oldAccRdd.unpersist(blocking = true) // I assume this will ensure all references to this cleared from memory
    log_info(s"Total row count on iteration: ${accRdd.count()}")
    iteration += 1
}
```

I've followed the advice from this: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/issues/1251, and am trying to avoid tweaking other configuration variables related to gc, memory fraction, and the jvm. Again, I am looking for an explanation to what may be going on, and how my assumptions of caching/checkpointing may be wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at some of the advice from our  memory page:
https://deeplearnin4j.org/memory

and https://deeplearning4j.org/spark

In general, deeplearning4j has its own off heap memory. You should be setting a lower batch size with more executors, pay attention to the javacpp off heap configuration and set the spark memory over head that's allowed.